# Are objects eligible for garbage collection after the page loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection

I'm wondering when references (specifically ones defined at a class level) go out of scope in .net web applications to better understand when they'd be eligible for garbage collection.

Currently I have code which looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  Object object = new Object();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // some code
  }
}
```

Would **object** go out of scope after the page loads (and be eligible for garbage collection) or would it be after the user navigates away from the page?

I typically create web applications in PHP so I'd guess that **object** would be eligible for GC after the page is done loading since it won't know when the user navigates away from the page.

Comment: It would only become available for GC once there are no more references to it, in this example that would be after the page request has completed.

Comment: Thanks James. Do you know if there are any instances where a Page could be placed on the large object heap, and thus be promoted to Gen 2 GC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP creates a new `Page` object whenever a request is made, and it does not hold onto the reference to that `Page` object once it sends the response back to the user, so as long as you don't find some way to hold onto a live reference to that `Page` object yourself, once the response is sent, the `Page` and all objects only accessible through that page become eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I got thrown into this project which was created by a lot of contractors so I wouldn't be surprised if they found a way to hold onto a reference to the page, so that gives me one more thing to look at. Thanks!

I'll wait a couple hours before accepting this as the answer to allow for others to chime in.